# How to get a wordpress taxonomy by meta data

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-fields

I have a custom post taxonomy to which i added 2 custom fields which are region and region_id.
I'd like to be able to query a single taxonomy by the custom fields
eg: query the taxonomy for region=1 & region_id=15.

I noticed wordpress doesn't use the wp_termtaxonomy table anymore for this kind of thing.
I used to have a wpdb call and it used to work with wp_termtaxonomy.

```
SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    WHERE `term_id` IN (
        SELECT `taxonomy_id` as `term_id`
        FROM $wpdb->taxonomymeta
        WHERE `taxonomy_id` IN(
            SELECT `taxonomy_id`
            FROM $wpdb->taxonomymeta
            WHERE  (`meta_key` = 'region_id' AND `meta_value` = $region_id)
            ) 
        AND (`meta_key` = 'region' AND `meta_value` = $region)
    )
    AND `taxonomy` = 'regions'
```

I'm not sure how to replicate this with the wp_options table since thats where wordpress stores taxonomy metadata.

Comment: As far as I know _taxonomymeta_ does not exist. You need to join `term_taxonomy` with `$wpdb->options` instead.

Comment: The question is how do I do that join but search the content of the wp-options table which stores the info in an array